# Is it possible to combine jsPDF and Autotable plugin?

Tags: jspdf

Is it possible to use jsPDF to grab text from a HTML page and jsPDF-autotable to grab the table and to get that all inside one PDF? I have a document which has some content, and tables in the middle of the content. However, I  was not able to print that document.

Sample code:
Sample code:`enter code here`

In the below code I am looping my Content array. Content can be of different types. For the table content am trying to use  pdf.autoTable and for the text content am using pdf.text

```
   var pdf = new jspdf('p', 'pt', 'a4');
     pdf.setFontSize(18);
    pdf.line(20, 25, 25, 25);

  for (let i = 0; i < this.dalSectionsArray.length; i++) {
  dynamicHtmlSource = dynamicHtmlSource + '<p style="text-align:left;"> 
      <b>' + this.dalSectionsArray[i].title + '</b></p><b/>';
    pdf.text(dynamicHtmlSource, 10+i, 10+i);
    for (let j = 0; j < this.dalContentsArray.length; j++) {
    if (this.dalSectionsArray[i].id === 
      this.dalContentsArray[j].sectionView.id) {
      if (this.dalContentsArray[j].subType === 'Clause') {
        dynamicHtmlSource = this.getClauseData(this.dalContentsArray[j]);
        pdf.text(dynamicHtmlSource,20+j,20+j);
      } else if (this.dalContentsArray[j].subType === 'Block') {
        dynamicHtmlSource = this.getBlockData(this.dalContentsArray[j]);
        pdf.text(dynamicHtmlSource,30+j,30+j);
      } else if (this.dalContentsArray[j].subType === 'Restriction') {
        dynamicHtmlSource = 
       this.getRestrictionData(this.dalContentsArray[j]);
        pdf.text(dynamicHtmlSource, 40+j, 40+j);
      } else if (this.dalContentsArray[j].subType === 'Table') {
        pdf.autoTable({
          startY:50+j,
          columnStyles: { europe: { halign: 'center' } }, // European 
       countries centered
          body: this.dalContentsArray[j].tableValues,
          columns: this.dalContentsArray[j].displayColumns
        })

      }
      } 

   pdf.fromHTML('',
   this.margins.left, // x coord
   this.margins.top,
   {
    // y coord
    width: this.margins.width// max width of content on PDF
    }, (dispose) => {
    this.headerFooterFormatting(pdf, pdf.internal.getNumberOfPages());
   },
   this.margins);

  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute;right:0; top:0; 
  bottom:0; height:100%; width:650px; padding:20px;');
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);

   pdf.setProperties({
   title: 'jspdf-iframe',
   subject: 'DAL Content',
   author: 'PDFAuthor',
   keywords: 'generated, javascript, web 2.0, ajax',
   creator: 'ABC'
   });
  iframe.src = pdf.output('datauristring');

 Issue is the pdf is completely messed and not printed properly.  Can any 
 one help me in this regard.
```

---

Sample JSON:

```
   {
  "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
  "sections": [
    {
      "title": "ABC",
      "description": "",
      "order": "1",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "id": "{b3cdda34-1fd2-4463-9aa0-24beff4b83fe}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d0006a2-0000-0c00-0000-5c94e5760000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-Section-{b3cdda34-1fd2-4463-9aa0-24beff4b83fe}-{1}",
      "type": "Section",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "FFFFF",
      "createdDate": "2018-11-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "FFFFF",
      "modifiedDate": "2018-11-12T00:00:00",
      "isactive": false
    },
    {
      "title": "DEF",
      "description": "",
      "order": "2",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "id": "{fca09906-dff9-40b2-a971-28fef7f37dbf}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d0004a2-0000-0c00-0000-5c94e5760000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-Section-{fca09906-dff9-40b2-a971-28fef7f37dbf}-{1}",
      "type": "Section",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "FFFFF",
      "createdDate": "2018-11-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "FFFFF",
      "modifiedDate": "2018-11-12T00:00:00",
      "isactive": false
    },
    {
      "title": "GHI",
      "description": "",
      "order": "3",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "id": "{9cfb60cf-354c-4194-9e2e-6bab41c6b280}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d00faa1-0000-0c00-0000-5c94e5750000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-Section-{9cfb60cf-354c-4194-9e2e-6bab41c6b280}-{1}",
      "type": "Section",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "FFFFF",
      "createdDate": "2018-11-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "FFFFF",
      "modifiedDate": "2018-11-12T00:00:00",
      "isactive": false
    }
  ],
  "contents": [
    {
      "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
      "baseDataid": "{a351366f-bf4b-44e0-94ff-a81be899ec3a}-{1}",
      "subType": "Table",
      "sectionView": {
        "id": "{9cfb60cf-354c-4194-9e2e-6bab41c6b280}-{1}",
        "title": "AAA",
        "description": "",
        "order": "4"
      },
      "title": "PL",
      "description": "",
      "order": "3",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "displayColumns": [ "N", "M", "O", "P" ],
      "tableValues": [
        {
          "N": "Level 21",
          "M": "22",
          "O": "",
          "P": "",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          "id": "6cb79b9f-2ef2-4d3a-b6c4-7d84dd61aaf7",
          "isDeleted": true,
          "N": "KKKKKKK",
          "M": "GBP 20M",
          "O": "",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          "id": "c83caf0b-8f00-4dc8-bf35-473bda398937",
          "isDeleted": true,
          "N": "EP",
          "M": "GBP 15M",
          "O": "",
          "isRowEditable": false
        }
      ],
      "placeHolderValues": "",
      "organizationDataView": [
        {
          "id": "{8b958d63-d605-4b9a-a3c4-a3c1c052316e}-{1}",
          "orgGroupName": "QQ",
          "orgGroupType": "DD",
          "orgLevel": 1,
          "orgParentGroupId": ""
        }
      ],
      "id": "{16a3fb1e-f7fa-4dfe-a4d3-c51b56c8dbee-uw}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d00a0ca-0000-0c00-0000-5c94ef3f0000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-CCCCOOOOO-{16a3fb1e-f7fa-4dfe-a4d3-c51b56c8dbee-uw}-{1}",
      "type": "CCCCOOOOO",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "MM",
      "createdDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "PPP",
      "modifiedDate": null,
      "isactive": false
    },
    {
      "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
      "baseDataid": "{2b498850-8f11-475d-b170-5705d05c4bf1}-{1}",
      "subType": "Clause",
      "sectionView": {
        "id": "{b3cdda34-1fd2-4463-9aa0-24beff4b83fe}-{1}",
        "title": "LLL",
        "description": "",
        "order": "3"
      },
      "title": "kkkkk",
      "Description": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "<br/>Some sample text here"
        }
      ],
      "order": "6",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "displayColumns": [],
      "tableValues": null,
      "placeHolderValues": "",
      "organizationDataView": [
        {
          "id": "{8b958d63-d605-4b9a-a3c4-a3c1c052316e}-{1}",
          "orgGroupName": "QQ",
          "orgGroupType": "DD",
          "orgLevel": 1,
          "orgParentGroupId": ""
        }
      ],
      "id": "{6193cef1-2fe5-47c2-8367-0650ab66caf3-uw}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d00a5ca-0000-0c00-0000-5c94ef400000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-CCCCOOOOO-{6193cef1-2fe5-47c2-8367-0650ab66caf3-uw}-{1}",
      "type": "CCCCOOOOO",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "MM",
      "createdDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "PPP",
      "modifiedDate": null,
      "isactive": false
    },
    {
      "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
      "baseDataid": "{d6793120-5e5b-40ec-a1ea-e82e7bdc9d1a}-{1}",
      "subType": "Clause",
      "sectionView": {
        "id": "{9cfb60cf-354c-4194-9e2e-6bab41c6b280}-{1}",
        "title": "UT",
        "description": "Sample Text",
        "order": "4"
      },
      "title": "PR",
      "Description": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "Sample"
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "Sample "
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "Sample"
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "Sample "
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "Sample"
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "any one programme/risk</li><li>a maximum premium of "
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "Sample"
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "<br/>SSample"
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "Sample"
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": ".Sample"
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": ", on Lloyd&#39;s paper, in respect of Canadian domiciled Property risks<br/>Your authority for Health extends to unlimited Healthcare where required by statute<br/>You may accept up to "
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": ", on Lloyd&#39;s paper, in respect of declarations under the Coast P&I Facility<br/>You may accept up to "
        },
        {
          "type": "dropDown",
          "value": "USD",
          "options": [ "USD", "INR", "Dollar" ]
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "value": "50"
        },
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": ", on Lloyd&#39;s paper, in respect of combined primary and excess grounding liability<br/>"
        }
      ],
      "order": "6",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "displayColumns": [],
      "tableValues": null,
      "placeHolderValues": "",
      "organizationDataView": [
        {
          "id": "{8b958d63-d605-4b9a-a3c4-a3c1c052316e}-{1}",
          "orgGroupName": "QQ",
          "orgGroupType": "DD",
          "orgLevel": 1,
          "orgParentGroupId": ""
        }
      ],
      "id": "{22505164-4d56-493e-8df2-b1bb53ab419a-uw}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d00acca-0000-0c00-0000-5c94ef400000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-CCCCOOOOO-{22505164-4d56-493e-8df2-b1bb53ab419a-uw}-{1}",
      "type": "CCCCOOOOO",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "MM",
      "createdDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "PPP",
      "modifiedDate": null,
      "isactive": false
    },
    {
      "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
      "baseDataid": "{ac949799-60c7-4f85-840f-f30203c5ee43}-{1}",
      "subType": "Block",
      "sectionView": {
        "id": "{fca09906-dff9-40b2-a971-28fef7f37dbf}-{1}",
        "title": "GR",
        "description": "",
        "order": "2"
      },
      "title": "",
      "description": "Sample",
      "order": "1",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "displayColumns": [],
      "tableValues": null,
      "placeHolderValues": "",
      "organizationDataView": [
        {
          "id": "{8b958d63-d605-4b9a-a3c4-a3c1c052316e}-{1}",
          "orgGroupName": "QQ",
          "orgGroupType": "DD",
          "orgLevel": 1,
          "orgParentGroupId": ""
        }
      ],
      "id": "{8652fedc-0d7c-48d8-bc3f-577294551671-uw}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d00baca-0000-0c00-0000-5c94ef400000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-CCCCOOOOO-{8652fedc-0d7c-48d8-bc3f-577294551671-uw}-{1}",
      "type": "CCCCOOOOO",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "MM",
      "createdDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "PPP",
      "modifiedDate": null,
      "isactive": false
    },
    {
      "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
      "baseDataid": "{522f1248-0882-4348-9bba-59c056c816c8}-{1}",
      "subType": "Clause",
      "sectionView": {
        "id": "{b3cdda34-1fd2-4463-9aa0-24beff4b83fe}-{1}",
        "title": "LLL",
        "description": "",
        "order": "3"
      },
      "title": "UP",
      "Description": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "Sample"
        }
      ],
      "order": "1",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "displayColumns": [],
      "tableValues": null,
      "placeHolderValues": "",
      "organizationDataView": [
        {
          "id": "{8b958d63-d605-4b9a-a3c4-a3c1c052316e}-{1}",
          "orgGroupName": "QQ",
          "orgGroupType": "DD",
          "orgLevel": 1,
          "orgParentGroupId": ""
        }
      ],
      "id": "{944eae3d-fa0f-4b0e-9c66-3499a16fc2fd-uw}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d00bfca-0000-0c00-0000-5c94ef400000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-CCCCOOOOO-{944eae3d-fa0f-4b0e-9c66-3499a16fc2fd-uw}-{1}",
      "type": "CCCCOOOOO",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "MM",
      "createdDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "PPP",
      "modifiedDate": null,
      "isactive": false
    },
    {
      "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
      "baseDataid": "{6c6a3c80-3536-4c51-8ccf-fcdc16d94090}-{1}",
      "subType": "Table",
      "sectionView": {
        "id": "{9cfb60cf-354c-4194-9e2e-6bab41c6b280}-{1}",
        "title": "KKPKPKPK",
        "description": "",
        "order": "4"
      },
      "title": "PT",
      "description": "",
      "order": "4",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "displayColumns": [ ".", "KKKKKKK", "EP", "P" ],
      "tableValues": [
        {
          ".": "Level 11",
          "KKKKKKK": "",
          "EP": "Level 21",
          "P": "",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          ".": "Asbestos - other than licensed removers",
          "KKKKKKK": "GBP 5M",
          "EP": ".",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          ".": "Auto manufacturing - safety critical components",
          "KKKKKKK": "GBP 10M",
          "EP": ".",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          ".": "Rail - contracting companies",
          "KKKKKKK": "GBP 5M",
          "EP": ".",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          ".": "Asbestos - other than licensed removers",
          "KKKKKKK": ".",
          "EP": "GBP 10M",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          ".": "Rail - contracting companies",
          "KKKKKKK": ".",
          "EP": "GBP 10M",
          "isRowEditable": false
        }
      ],
      "placeHolderValues": "",
      "organizationDataView": [
        {
          "id": "{8b958d63-d605-4b9a-a3c4-a3c1c052316e}-{1}",
          "orgGroupName": "QQ",
          "orgGroupType": "DD",
          "orgLevel": 1,
          "orgParentGroupId": "."
        }
      ],
      "id": "{91de8a0b-4156-4121-be05-844b03928c29-uw}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d00c5ca-0000-0c00-0000-5c94ef410000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-CCCCOOOOO-{91de8a0b-4156-4121-be05-844b03928c29-uw}-{1}",
      "type": "CCCCOOOOO",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "MM",
      "createdDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "PPP",
      "modifiedDate": null,
      "isactive": false
    },
    {
      "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
      "baseDataid": "{92860693-e038-4a58-814c-6a74d59e7cce}-{1}",
      "subType": "Clause",
      "sectionView": {
        "id": "{9cfb60cf-354c-4194-9e2e-6bab41c6b280}-{1}",
        "title": "KKPKPKPK",
        "description": "",
        "order": "4"
      },
      "title": "",
      "Description": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "Sample"
        }
      ],

      "order": "9",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "displayColumns": [],
      "tableValues": null,
      "placeHolderValues": "",
      "organizationDataView": [
        {
          "id": "{8b958d63-d605-4b9a-a3c4-a3c1c052316e}-{1}",
          "orgGroupName": "QQ",
          "orgGroupType": "DD",
          "orgLevel": 1,
          "orgParentGroupId": ""
        }
      ],
      "id": "{af17341e-a88c-4564-8296-c513e3708af2-uw-per}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d00e3ca-0000-0c00-0000-5c94ef420000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-CCCCOOOOO-{af17341e-a88c-4564-8296-c513e3708af2-uw-per}-{1}",
      "type": "CCCCOOOOO",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "MM",
      "createdDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "PPP",
      "modifiedDate": null,
      "isactive": false
    },
    {
      "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
      "baseDataid": "{92860693-e038-4a58-814c-6a74d59e7cce}-{1}",
      "subType": "Clause",
      "sectionView": {
        "id": "{9cfb60cf-354c-4194-9e2e-6bab41c6b280}-{1}",
        "title": "KKPKPKPK",
        "description": "",
        "order": "4"
      },
      "title": "PL",

      "Description": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "Sample"
        }
      ],
      "order": "7",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "displayColumns": [],
      "tableValues": null,
      "placeHolderValues": "",
      "organizationDataView": [
        {
          "id": "{8b958d63-d605-4b9a-a3c4-a3c1c052316e}-{1}",
          "orgGroupName": "QQ",
          "orgGroupType": "DD",
          "orgLevel": 1,
          "orgParentGroupId": ""
        }
      ],
      "id": "{af17341e-a88c-4564-8296-c513e3708af2-uw}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d00e8ca-0000-0c00-0000-5c94ef420000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-CCCCOOOOO-{af17341e-a88c-4564-8296-c513e3708af2-uw}-{1}",
      "type": "CCCCOOOOO",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "MM",
      "createdDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "PPP",
      "modifiedDate": null,
      "isactive": false
    },

    {
      "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
      "baseDataid": "{92c5bd05-c8a2-45c1-a1e9-fd3f78c705ab}-{1}",
      "subType": "Table",
      "sectionView": {
        "id": "{9cfb60cf-354c-4194-9e2e-6bab41c6b280}-{1}",
        "title": "KKPKPKPK",
        "description": "",
        "order": "4"
      },
      "title": "KKPKPKPK PP",
      "description": "",
      "order": "1",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "displayColumns": [ "N", "kkk", "LPLPLPL", "Ccy", "M", "LTLT", "P" ],
      "tableValues": [
        {
          "N": "Level 11",
          "kkk": "",
          "LPLPLPL": "",
          "Ccy": "",
          "M": "",
          "LTLT": "",
          "P": "",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          "N": "Level 11",
          "kkk": "",
          "LPLPLPL": "",
          "Ccy": "",
          "M": "11",
          "LTLT": "",
          "P": "",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          "N": "QQQl",
          "kkk": "QQQQ",
          "LPLPLPL": "DDDD",
          "Ccy": "GBP",
          "M": "10M",
          "LTLT": "Any one vessel",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          "N": "Marine Cargo",
          "kkk": "QIEL",
          "LPLPLPL": "Lineslip and other non-coverholder facilities",
          "Ccy": "GBP",
          "M": "5M",
          "LTLT": "Any one event",
          "isRowEditable": false
        },
        {
          "N": "KKKK",
          "kkk": "PPPP",
          "LPLPLPL": "DDDD",
          "Ccy": "GBP",
          "M": "20M",
          "LTLT": "Any one vessel",
          "isRowEditable": false
        }
      ],
      "placeHolderValues": "",
      "organizationDataView": [
        {
          "id": "{8b958d63-d605-4b9a-a3c4-a3c1c052316e}-{1}",
          "orgGroupName": "QQ",
          "orgGroupType": "DD",
          "orgLevel": 1,
          "orgParentGroupId": ""
        }
      ],
      "id": "{d036bc60-db2d-4c93-86ff-981a62e207ca-uw}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d00eacb-0000-0c00-0000-5c94ef530000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-CCCCOOOOO-{d036bc60-db2d-4c93-86ff-981a62e207ca-uw}-{1}",
      "type": "CCCCOOOOO",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "MM",
      "createdDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "PPP",
      "modifiedDate": null,
      "isactive": false
    },

    {
      "dalId": "{QQ-4b3544ef-3821-439c-84cf-b6f18c9a86fc-uw}-{1}",
      "baseDataid": "{bf1f6e82-6afd-4837-81ab-acabc665da14}-{1}",
      "subType": "Clause",
      "sectionView": {
        "id": "{b3cdda34-1fd2-4463-9aa0-24beff4b83fe}-{1}",
        "title": "LLL",
        "description": "",
        "order": "3"
      },
      "title": "klklkl",

      "Description": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "value": "sAMPLE tEXT"
        }
      ],
      "order": "4",
      "status": "Active",
      "startDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "endDate": null,
      "displayColumns": [],
      "tableValues": null,
      "placeHolderValues": "",
      "organizationDataView": [
        {
          "id": "{8b958d63-d605-4b9a-a3c4-a3c1c052316e}-{1}",
          "orgGroupName": "QQ",
          "orgGroupType": "DD",
          "orgLevel": 1,
          "orgParentGroupId": ""
        }
      ],
      "id": "{QQ-851f96e7-542f-4a57-a0b1-35feb4698f5e-uw}-{1}",
      "_etag": "\"0d0062cc-0000-0c00-0000-5c94ef5a0000\"",
      "partitionKey": "GGG-CCCCOOOOO-{QQ-851f96e7-542f-4a57-a0b1-35feb4698f5e-uw}-{1}",
      "type": "CCCCOOOOO",
      "clientId": "GGG",
      "createdBy": "MM",
      "createdDate": "2018-12-12T00:00:00",
      "modifiedBy": "PPP",
      "modifiedDate": null,
      "isactive": false
    }
  ]
}
   getClauseData(dalContentdata) {
    let dynamicClauseHtmlSource = '<h4>' + dalContentdata.title + '</h4>';
    dynamicClauseHtmlSource = dynamicClauseHtmlSource + '<p></p>';
    dynamicClauseHtmlSource = dynamicClauseHtmlSource + + '<p style="text-align:justify;line-height:0.3em">' + dalContentdata.description + '</p>';
    dynamicClauseHtmlSource = this.brToNewLine(dynamicClauseHtmlSource);
    return dynamicClauseHtmlSource;
  }

  getBlockData(dalContentdata) {
    let dynamicBlockHtmlSource = '<h4>' + dalContentdata.title + '</h4>';
    dynamicBlockHtmlSource = dynamicBlockHtmlSource + '<p></p>';
    dynamicBlockHtmlSource = dynamicBlockHtmlSource + dalContentdata.description;
    dynamicBlockHtmlSource = this.brToNewLine(dynamicBlockHtmlSource);
    return dynamicBlockHtmlSource;
  }

  getTableData(dalContentdata) {
    let tableSource = "<table>";
    tableSource = tableSource + "<tr>";

    for (var k = 0; k < dalContentdata.displayColumns.length; k++) {
      tableSource = tableSource + "<th style='word-wrap: break-word'>" + dalContentdata.displayColumns[k] + "</th>";
    }
    tableSource = tableSource + "</tr>";

    for (var j = 0; j < dalContentdata.tableValues.length; j++) {
      tableSource = tableSource + "<tr>";
      for (var k = 0; k < dalContentdata.displayColumns.length; k++) {
        tableSource = tableSource + "<td style='word-wrap: break-word'>" + dalContentdata.tableValues[0][dalContentdata.displayColumns[k]] + "</td>";
      }
      tableSource = tableSource + "</tr>";
    }
    tableSource = tableSource + "</table>";
    return tableSource;
    }

 brToNewLine(str) {
    return str.replace(/<br ?\/?>/g, "\n");
  }
```

Comment: Please share code which you have tried so far and sample code with expected result

Comment: @NagaSaiA I have pasted the code above. Am looping through an Array of objects to form a document. There depending on the subtype, am calling a method which returns a string. That string am passing to pdf.text method. for tables am using pdf.autotable. Any help will be helpful

Comment: @NagaSaiA Any help on this one pls ?

Comment: working with your code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/agdoMw?editors=1010 , I will post my answer in few mins ..issue is lot of missing parameters - dalSectionsArray, dalContentsArray, getClauseData

Comment: please add html and missing variables code

Comment: @NagaSaiA  Added JSON content in my comment.

Comment: @NagaSaiA Also Added methods to get the HTMl from the JSON. Here HTML Code is not required. All Am doing is looping through JSON and forming HTML String and passing it to JSPDF.

Comment: @NagaSaiA Thanks for the help.

Comment: tried modifying mentioned code , it is downloading and printing table but alignment issue with data - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/agdoMw?editors=1010

Comment: it seems you are trying to print multiple tables and current logic only picks last table array

Comment: @NagaSaiAThat is the issue am having. It needs to print all the data with all the tables. Is the way am |using . Is the data printing correctly for you. For me data is overlapped. Table is printed on the text.

Comment: @NagaSaiA May I please know if you can help in this issue.